# How to reffer to workbooks-worksheet and range as variables

Tags: excel, vba

I get all the time runtime error 9, “subscript out of range” . Dont know how to do this. I get the error by the last line of code below.

```
Dim Sheetstarybpm As Worksheet
Dim countrowsoldbpm1 As Long
Dim rng2 As Range

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select BPM Report for previous month"
        .ButtonName = "OK"
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        oldbpm = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With

Workbooks.Open oldbpm

Set Sheetstarybpm = ActiveSheet

countrowsoldbpm1 = Range("a10", Range("a10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Set myrange = Range("A10:CW" & countrowsoldbpm1)

Set rng2 = Workbooks(oldbpm).Worksheets(Sheetstarybpm).Range(myrange)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the object methods incorrectly. Once you have stored the `Sheetstarybpm` you can use this further... So when opening the workbook store this as a workbook object so you can reference it later on, if needed. Additionally, when setting your worksheet object you can now explicitly reference your workbook because you have stored it (much better coding practice). It is also recommended to explicitly define your sheet object references when setting your ranges. Please see amended code below.

```vb
Dim Sheetstarybpm As Worksheet
Dim countrowsoldbpm1 As Long
Dim myWB As Workbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select BPM Report for previous month"
        .ButtonName = "OK"
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        oldbpm = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With

Set myWB = Workbooks.Open(oldbpm)

Set Sheetstarybpm = myWB.ActiveSheet

countrowsoldbpm1 = Sheetstarybpm.Range("a10", Range("a10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Set myrange = Sheetstarybpm.Range("A10:CW" & countrowsoldbpm1)
```

**Edit**: Removed `rng2` from the code because it is the same as `myrange`, as noted by OP in comments.

Comment: Thank You for Your comment. Now by the line : Set rng2 = Sheetstarybpm.Range(myrange) I get the error Run time errror 21004, Method Range of object _Worksheet failed

Comment: @Marc Oh yes, I see. What are you trying to set `rng2` to? You cannot pass a `Range` object through a `.Range` method. Is there a difference between `myrange` and `rng2`?

Comment: Oh Yes, You are right. It is the same. Thank You for your help!

Comment: @Marc great. Please mark (no pun intended) this as your answer to close the ticket.